# Enormous highlighting for Cancel button on profile picture change popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-picture

Highlighting of "Cancel" button while editing [profile's image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) looks bigger than needed (screenshot was taken after the mouse down for better visibility):

> [image: Too big cancel]

Comment: repro'd. on win 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this is going out in our next build, hopefully today yet. I think the *entirety* of choosing a new avatar should be rebuilt, but hey, those buttons should look better now.